# MYSQL: clause where comparison Integer value

Tags: mysql, sql

i've got a column int but when i request a select with the clause 
WHERE id='1FR2' 
for example, MYSQL return true with the record id=1
So it seems the MYSQL ignore or convert ?
A solution to force MYSQL to not trim it ?
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you even compare a int with a string which is not a number?

Comment: MySQL's casting rules will attempt to get all numeric characters from the left of the string.  If the value is expected to be an integer, you should validate it as such before passing it to the query.

Comment: thanks Michael, but i'm a little confused with Mysql casting rules. Off course all input are validate, example here is for request parameters or other javascript values users can change before request. Then all sql query paramters are escaped, and i thought it was enough. An now i understand that i have to validate all query parameters before because of mysql rules. Not a good news

Answer (score 1):

This is because of MySQL converts string into integer. So it takes the first number(s) and truncate all other string. The solution is cast `id` to char first like this:

```
WHERE cast(id as char)='1FR2'
```

Comment: Thanks but i think the mysql ignore index when using cast. I will try a test

Comment: Of course it ignore index